# Java program compile error: `.Class required`

Tags: java

I am new to JAVA and am trying to create a `Stack` with a certain capacity in the constructor of the class.

However at compile time, I am getting errors as follows :

> sh-4.2# javac ArrayStack.java
>
> ArrayStack.java:12: error: '.class' expected
> ArrayStack(int capacity);
> ^
> ArrayStack.java:12: error: ';' expected
> ArrayStack(int capacity);

My code is as follows :

```
import java.lang.* ;

public class ArrayStack<E>   
{
 private E[] stack;
 public static void main(String[] args) {

ArrayStack(int capacity);
{
      stack = (E[]) (new Object[capacity]);
}  }  }
```

I couldn't understand the issue, here . Can someone please help me out on this?

Comment: I would recommend you to start with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html so as to get basic understanding of the java program structure

Comment: I agree with @MohamedSanaulla . You should use indentation. Without indentation it is difficult to help you to sort out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problems are:

1. **Semicolon after constructor declaration**
2. **Constructor definition inside main method**

none of them is supported in the Java programming language:

```
public class ArrayStack<E> {
    private E[] stack;

    ArrayStack(int capacity); {
        stack = (E[]) (new Object[capacity]);
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    }
}
```